# Does $\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = -\partial_\mu F^{\nu\mu}$?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

I know that $\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = \dfrac{4\pi}{c}J^\nu$

and $F^{\mu\nu} = -F^{\nu\mu}$

But does $\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu} = -\partial_\mu F^{\nu\mu}$?

PS: if the contraction index is $\nu$, is this right?

$\partial_\nu F^{\mu\nu} = -\dfrac{4\pi}{c}J^\mu$

Comment: Yes and yes (filling space)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the partial derivate is a linear operator. So $\partial_\mu (a F^{ \nu \mu}) = a \partial_\mu F^{ \nu \mu}$.

Also, yes, the last statement is correct.

Comment: What about if $a$ is a matric like $\partial_\mu (g_{\mu\nu} F^{ \nu \mu}) = g_{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu F^{ \nu \mu}$ ?

Comment: @Firestar-Reimu Then you need to derive the metric as well.